# WARN o.s.a.r.l.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler - Execution of Rabbit message listener failed

Tags: spring-mvc, servlets, rabbitmq, java, rabbitmq-exchange

There are 2 Spring projects 'A' and 'B'. Both of them uses seperate databases. The idea is to keep these databases in Sync. Sync is done via exchanging Jav POJO objects between projects. 'A' has a java web api to handle requests. When API call is made, 'A' communicates POJO to 'B' through messaging channel using Rabbit MQ. But Iam getting the below exception when the above action is performed:

```
2016-05-21 10:29:02,335 INFO  o.mmc.bbc.manager.bbcSiteEventReceived - GenericMessage [payload=org.mmc.bbc.site.events.pseledapi2016.PSELEDAPICustomerRegistrationEventDetail@1cae82, headers={amqp_consumerQueue=bbcSiteEventQueue, id=52e3c373-7acb-c419-7026-da98f101409f, method=siteCustomerRegistered, interface=org.mmc.bbc.site.events.pseledapi2016.PSELEDAPICustomerEventHandler, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-lP9F34F3q7iDys4iC_pAPA, timestamp=1463840942335}]
2016-05-21 10:29:02,772 WARN  o.s.a.r.l.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler - Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:864) ~[spring-rabbit-1.4.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:759) ~[spring-rabbit-1.4.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:679) ~[spring-rabbit-1.4.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:83) [spring-rabbit-1.4.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:170) ~[spring-rabbit-1.4.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1257) [spring-rabbit-1.4.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:660) ~[spring-rabbit-1.4.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1021) [spring-rabbit-1.4.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$100(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:83) [spring-rabbit-1.4.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$2.doInTransaction(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:991) [spring-rabbit-1.4.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$2.doInTransaction(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:984) [spring-rabbit-1.4.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133) [spring-tx-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:984) [spring-rabbit-1.4.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$700(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:83) [spring-rabbit-1.4.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1119) [spring-rabbit-1.4.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_66]
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: ; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.principal': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider dmmcning a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:78) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:71) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:99) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.monitor.SimpleMessageHandlerMetrics.handleMessage(SimpleMessageHandlerMetrics.java:107) ~[spring-integration-jmx-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.monitor.SimpleMessageHandlerMetrics.invoke(SimpleMessageHandlerMetrics.java:87) ~[spring-integration-jmx-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy301.handleMessage(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:287) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:245) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.monitor.DirectChannelMetrics.monitorSend(DirectChannelMetrics.java:114) ~[spring-integration-jmx-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.monitor.DirectChannelMetrics.doInvoke(DirectChannelMetrics.java:98) ~[spring-integration-jmx-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.monitor.DirectChannelMetrics.invoke(DirectChannelMetrics.java:92) ~[spring-integration-jmx-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy297.send(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) ~[spring-messaging-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) ~[spring-messaging-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:95) ~[spring-messaging-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:101) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$400(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:45) ~[spring-integration-amqp-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$1.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:93) ~[spring-integration-amqp-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:756) ~[spring-rabbit-1.4.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.principal': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider dmmcning a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:352) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35) ~[spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:187) ~[spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy334.getName(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.mmc.bbc.manager.core.pseled2016.PSELEDCustomerManagerImpl.siteCustomerRegistered(PSELEDCustomerManagerImpl.java:264) ~[PSELEDCustomerManagerImpl.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy364.siteCustomerRegistered(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:203) ~[spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.mmc.bbc.manager.core.bbcSiteEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(bbcSiteEventDispatcher.java:37) ~[bbcSiteEventDispatcher.class:na]
    at org.mmc.bbc.manager.core.bbcSiteEventDispatcher$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$52b1cf10.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717) ~[spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653) ~[spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.mmc.bbc.manager.core.bbcSiteEventDispatcher$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d10fe7c3.dispatchEvent(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:112) ~[spring-expression-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:129) ~[spring-expression-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:49) ~[spring-expression-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:342) ~[spring-expression-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88) ~[spring-expression-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:131) ~[spring-expression-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:330) ~[spring-expression-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:164) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:276) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:142) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:75) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 55 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131) ~[spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.AbstractRequestAttributesScope.get(AbstractRequestAttributesScope.java:41) ~[spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 104 common frames omitted
```

Could anyone let me know why thiserror is happening?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -3):

scopedTarget.principal is available from the request scope only.

Comment: And why is that relevant? What's the alternative? Please clarify your answer.